# Edit a particular cell in uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

I have a table view cell in which I am using an action sheet to change the language of the app. After the action has happened I want to change the displayed language title. How can I access that cell? Can I use subscripts to call and edit the button title for that cell??

```
 let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title:NSLocalizedString("Message", comment: "Message"), message:"", preferredStyle:.actionSheet)
    //
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"English", style:.default, handler: { (action) in
        Bundle.setLanguage("en")
                                        self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated:true, completion:nil)
        self.languageSelected.text = "English"
        self.cell.notificationButton.setTitle("English" , for: .normal )
        self.lang = 0
        self.langChange()
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////
   func langChange() {
if lang == 0 {
cell.notificationButton.setTitle("English" , for: .normal )}
if lang == 1 {
cell.notificationButton.setTitle("Hindi" , for: .normal )}
if lang == 2 {
cell.notificationButton.setTitle("Tamil" , for: .normal )}
if lang == 3 {
cell.notificationButton.setTitle("Telugu" , for: .normal )}
}



   ////////////////////////////////////////

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! AppSettingViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.leftText.text = menuArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    if lang == 0 {
        cell.notificationButton.setTitle("English" , for: .normal )}
    if lang == 1 {
        cell.notificationButton.setTitle("Hindi" , for: .normal )}
    if lang == 2 {
        cell.notificationButton.setTitle("Tamil" , for: .normal )}
    if lang == 3 {
        cell.notificationButton.setTitle("Telugu" , for: .normal )}
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.notificationButton = UIButton()
        cell.languageLabel = UILabel()
        cell.addSubview(cell.notificationButton)
        cell.addSubview(cell.languageLabel)
        languageSelected.textColor = appGreenTheme
         cell.languageLabel.text = languageSelected.text
        cell.languageLabel.textColor = appGreenTheme
        cell.languageLabel.isHidden = true
        cell.notificationButton.setTitleColor(appGreenTheme, for: .normal)
        cell.notificationButton.isHidden = false
```

..
I tried to change it with a lot of techniques, but the title at the first cell is not changing. Please can anyone help?

Comment: Hello, From where you present the action sheet?

Comment: the action sheet is presented when the user tap on very first cell of the tableview ,which is a language setting tab

Comment: Can you Please share the output table view screenshot.

Comment: sure did. hope it helps

Comment: Tell me which **notificationButton** title you want to change while click action sheet option

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case as your change does not require cell layout change (by layout change i mean no height calculation involved in changing the cell), you can use following

```
....
self.languageSelected.text = "English"
self.cell.notificationButton.setTitle("English" , for: .normal )
self.lang = 0
self.langChange()

let cell = YOUR_TABLEVIEW_REF.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: YOUR_ROW_FOR_LANGUAGE_CELL, section: YOUR_SECTION_FOR_LANGUAGE_CELL)) as! AppSettingViewCell

// REST OF YOUR LOGIC TO CHANGE THE CELL CONTENT BASED ON YOUR IMPLEMENTATION.
```

`cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath)` will grab the cell which is currently showing in the given indexPath. As you tapped the cell and show the action sheet, it's fairly clear that, the cell is currently being rendered. Calling the `cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath)` will return you that cell.

[Appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow)

Comment: While technically correct, your answer lacks one vital information - unless OP persists the data somewhere(some kind of model) it will revert back to the original value after scrolling the tableview enough sonthat the cell gets reused.

Comment: i cannot call it from action sheet. cellforrow at is not appsettingcell is not a member of it. also if i call from the tableview cellforrow at method then, it wont be updated after setting is changed

Comment: Yes you are correct, OP has to persist the status of the current language, i assume that OP already read the current set language from persistent storage in the `cellForRow` tableview datasource.

Comment: i think you are talking about accessing the `tableview` reference inside `UIAlertAction`, right ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are saving your `UITableViewCell` in the enclosing class and are trying to modify it via that reference. I am not sure whether that could work, but I know that it isn't a recommended way of changing your cell.

Instead you should change the language in the `cellForRowAt()` function, like you are already attempting to do. What's missing is that when `langChange()` is called, the function just needs to know your `UITableView` and call `reloadData()`:

```
func langChange() {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Why does that work?**

`reloadData()` forces the table to reload all of its cells, since it thinks that the data set which it is based on has changed. At this point, `cellForRowAt()` is called again for every currently displayed cell. Inside `cellForRowAt()` you will now check what language is selected and set the cell's title according to the language.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to change the title that will be displayed in the action sheet after the language change in the specified cell, right?
If so, try using a **delegate**.

Example: In your cell class, create a function or an @IBAction to open its action sheet in the main View and pass its cell as parameter, when your main View receives its parameter (the cell), use **tableView.indexPath** (for: cell of the parameter) that it will give you the specific indexPath of the cell that opened its action sheet and through it you change the title